# Error al obtener datos de usuario con API de Facebook Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-api

estuve realizando una integración de la API de Facebook en un sitio web para que los usuarios pudieran iniciar sesión con ella, hago todos los pasos según la documentación oficial y pido el nombre, apellido y correo electrónico del usuario, al inicio funcionaba bien pero después de cierto tiempo aveces me trae soló nombre y apellido pero el correo electrónico no logra obtenerlo, en otras ocasiones no trae ningún dato, solamente me devuelve 'undefined', ya revise los permisos en la consola de desarrollador en Facebook Developer y están correctamente, revise y el código esta implementado de la manera correcta para pedir los datos, este es el código que uso para solicitar la información del usuario a la hora de iniciar sesión:

```
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', { fields : 'name,first_name,last_name,email' }, function (response) {
        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
        onSendDataFacebook(response);
    });
}
```

Agradecería si supieran a que se debe este comportamiento de la API.

Answer (score 0):

El usuario de Facebook puede (o no se si esta opción está activa por defecto) denegar el acceso a datos personales.

En otras palabras desde el problema de Facebook con el uso de la información, estos datos están bloqueados, así que si el usuario no puso su **email** como información pública, no te lo va a dar.

> En resumen es el comportamiento normal de la API.